Rad Studio C++ Menu items are greyed out
I am new to RAD STUDIO C++ Builder and I am given a task to write a program by my current company. I have created some Menu Items and sub items to write Actions in case of a click event.
But the problem is that the items are greyed out and my click actions are not getting executed when i click the items.
Menu item and the sub items are enabled = True and Visible = True.



If you tie a menu item to an TAction then it is the TAction that needs to be enabled.

Do you have TAction objects or OnClick handlers assigned to your menu items? We can't see that in your screenshot

I forgot to close the issue, I solved it already.

Enabling TAction and creating ExitActionExecute function solved my problem.
void __fastcall TForm1::ExitActionExecute(TObject *Sender)
{
// function to show up the element
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

